# What are Qt style sheets for and how they work?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtstylesheets

I know that there is Qt Widgets that works natively (a button is an OS button) and there is QtQuick/QML items that are rendered by Qt (a button is a shape rendered in OpenGL context). And now I see there are Qt Style Sheets that work with QPushButton and other types, so I'm a little bit confused:

1. How to Qt Style Sheets work inside?
2. How can they affect they way a native button is rendered?
3. Do you need it at all when there's QML?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In accordance with [Qt documentations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets) QWidgets are not system widgets  by default since Qt 4.4. They calls it *Alien Widgets*. So all widgets in modern Qt are rendered by Qt itself. Therefore they can be rendered with any style you want.

Comment: @DenisCutcher Yes, they do.

Answer (score 1):

And to answer your question 3:

Have a look at https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling for setting QML styles. Basically, everything can be done with QML, no need for extra .qss style sheet as for Qt Widgets.